# Wrapper function ExternalInterface.call not working

Tags: actionscript

When I do my wrapper call `safeExternalCall("ToggleLoadingIcon", m_PlayerId, shouldShow);`, the JavaScript function `ToggleLoadingIcon` is never called. However, when I do `ExternalInterface.call("ToggleLoadingIcon", m_PlayerId, shouldShow);`, it works. Why is that?

ActionScript:

```
private function showHideSpinner(shouldShow:Boolean):void
{
    //this does not work
    safeExternalCall("ToggleLoadingIcon", m_PlayerId, shouldShow);
    //but this works
    //ExternalInterface.call("ToggleLoadingIcon", m_PlayerId, shouldShow);
}

private function safeExternalCall(functionName:String, ... args):void
{
    try
    {
        if(ExternalInterface.call(functionName, args) == null)
        {
            //do some logging
        }
    }
    catch(error:Error)
    {
        //do some more logging
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got some errors ?

Comment: I didn't see any errors in the IDE or when exporting my code to SWF

Comment: I meant when your are testing the project in the browser. Try to use a [debug version of Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) and of course take a look on your browser's developer console ...

Answer (score 0):

There is property ExternalInterface.available, first clue is to add some text field or connect with debugger and see if its true.